# Submitting multiple forms in HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, osticket

I'm relatively new to HTML and JavaScript and i'm currently modifying a company osTicket.

I'm trying to submit 2 forms in the same page (i'm aware that HTML does not support this) through delaying the second submission with JavaScript, but i think there's something wrong with my code or way of thinking.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function x() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            <?php // Just normal validation, checking if has administrator privileges or not
            if(!defined('OSTSCPINC') || !$thisstaff || !$thisstaff->canEditTickets() || !$ticket) die('Access Denied');

            $info=Format::htmlchars(($errors && $_POST)?$_POST:$ticket->getUpdateInfo());
            if ($_POST)
                $info['duedate'] = Format::date($cfg->getDateFormat(),
                strtotime($info['duedate']));

            echo '<form id="reply" action="tickets.php?id=' . $ticket->getId() . '#reply" name="reply1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">';
            csrf_token();

            echo '<input type="hidden" name="do" value="update">'; // Fields that are mandatory for the form but don't want them to show
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="a" value="edit">';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $ticket->getId() . '">';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="' . $info['user_id'] . '">';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="source" value="' . $info['source'] . '">';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="topicId" value="' . $info['topicId'] . '">';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="slaId" value="' . $info['slaId']  . '">';
            echo '</form>';?>
            document.forms['reply1'].submit(); // The second form
        }, 2000);
    }
</script>

<form id="reply" action="tickets.php?id=<?php echo $ticket->getId();?>#reply" name="reply" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- a lot of code that it is working properly -->

    <input class="btn_sm" type='submit' value="<?php echo __('Post Reply');?>" onclick="x()">
</form>
```

The first `if` in PHP is just to prevent normal users from submitting this form, i'm logged in with administration access. All of the HTML and PHP is code that was already written and should work normally (except for syntax erros) and i also tested by submitting each form individually and works as expected.

Also, the first form submits normally with no errors, but the second seems like it doesn't get executed. I'm open to improvement in the code and advises, thanks !

Comment: is jQuery ok to use?

Comment: Why do you use document.write() an php echo? you can directly echo in html: <input type="hidden" name="topic_id" value="<?php echo $value ?>">. You can use Ajax to submit different requests and process result in javascript or if you don't need multiple interactions you can simply group your form variables in different arrays and process them with php after.

Comment: @YuriBlanc, well it does get much easier to understand

Comment: that way it would be ` $('form').submit(function(e){ // on a form submit
        e.preventDefault(); //do not submit
        serializedData = $("form").serialize(); //serialise all forms to JSON
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: tickets.php,
            data: serializedData,
            success: function(){// do on success},
            dataType: json
        });
    });`

Comment: It's not much easier to understand, it's exactly the opposite. And `document.write()` is a bad practice, and bad idea, for this purposes. You can crash completely your application with that sentence. It's better `appendChild` or `innerHTML` to paint with javascript. But I think that @YuriBlanc said is the best you can do.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude, what i meant was: "with the `echo`, it get's much easier to understand"

Comment: Ah OK! Sorry for the misunderstanding :(

Comment: @Flippy you should consider thinking about your js and php separately when trying a proof of concept or debugging; they invoke at different times on different machines and thus work independently to eachother

Comment: @PaulS., how would you advise in this situation ?

Comment: You create a php script that is the server side logic and you use ajax request to fullfill your needs. So you can also use json and make your js application dynamic and easy to mantain. WIth php you can json_encode/jsoc_decode and json is == to javascript objects.

Comment: It's a good advice and i will keep that in mind, but i'm editing files that were already written and since i don't know most of the logic behind the platform, i thought this were the easiest solution

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery

```
$('form').submit(function(e){ // on a form submit
    e.preventDefault(); //do not submit
    serializedData = $("form").serialize(); //serialise all forms to JSON
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: tickets.php,
        data: serializedData,
        success: function(){
            // do on success
        },
        dataType: json
    });
});
```

without:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'tickets.php', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
var data = JSON.stringify([].slice.call(forms));
request.send(data);
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: forms.serialize is not a function(…)`

Comment: because serialize() is a jQuery function!

Comment: oops, you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery

Comment: @Thomas, based on the link won't my problem be the same ? 
Even by changing the form into a JS object or other, it will be sent as a form and it won't be able two process both at the same time, right ?

Comment: nope because you put all the form's data into the array.

Comment: @Flippy Instead of sending 1 form's data, it sends all the forms on the page as 1 big JSON string